# compiling iptables module error

Tags: sockets, compilation, kernel, iptables

I am tring to test, for the first time, an old iptables modules that filter modbus protocol, i used an old fedora 7 to avoid the compatibility problem,i activate the module in the config kernel, but when i tried to do a make, i had some problemes related to  skbuff.h library function:

```
[root@localhost linux-2.6.38.4]# make
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
  CHK     include/generated/compile.h
  CC [M]  net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.o
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:18: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:18: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘EXPORT_NO_SYMBOLS’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: In function ‘length_check’:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:61: warning: suggest parentheses around && within ||
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: In function ‘match’:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:141: error: ‘const struct sk_buff’ has no member named ‘nh’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:138: warning: unused variable ‘data’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: In function ‘checkentry’:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:194: error: implicit declaration of function ‘IPT_ALIGN’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:187: warning: unused variable ‘modbusinfo’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: At top level:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: error: variable ‘modbus_match’ has initializer but incomplete type
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: error: extra brace group at end of initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: error: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: excess elements in struct initializer
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:202: warning: (near initialization for ‘modbus_match’)
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: In function ‘init’:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:206: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ipt_register_match’
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c: In function ‘cleanup’:
net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c:211: error: implicit declaration of function ‘ipt_unregister_match’
make[3]: *** [net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** [net/ipv4/netfilter] Error 2
make[1]: *** [net/ipv4] Error 2
make: *** [net] Error 2
[root@localhost linux-2.6.38.4]#
```

the line that triger the first error is line 141:

```
  iph = skb->nh.iph;
```

i searched and i did found that there is some change in the skbuff.h, some functions are not available anymore.
this is the source that present the file that of my iptabe module ,https://github.com/kinger1172/ralink_rt5350/blob/1efdc7986ae8b0fb6780311c9e7eea2bd161828f/SDK_4_0_0_0/RT288x_SDK/source/linux-2.4.x/net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c

i cant update my kernel because the module will not work then, so if anyone have an idea or patch to resolve this problems, i will be greatfull.

Comment: There is no file `net/ipv4/netfilter/ipt_modbus.c` in the vanilla Linux kernel 2.6.38. (See, e.g. [here](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/netfilter/?v=2.6.38)). Where have you taken it?

Comment: yes, ipt_modbus is an extending module you can download from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/modbusfw/files/ , all you need to do is just to add it to your netfilter and recompile de linux kernel